# How to implement simple listener for STRING?

Tags: c#, .net

Using [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) I want to implement some listener for simple class which periodically changes internal **STRING** variable.

Any clue how it could be implemented?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an example on the [MSDN INotifyPropertyChanged page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).